# How to get import custom tasks more than once without warning message?

Tags: msbuild-task

I'm using some custom tasks from MSBuild Extension Pack (MEP). My projects are splitted among many files. In those files I import the MEP tasks using  (twice or three times in two/three files). I receive the warning message when doing this like:

> ... warning MSB4011: "C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\ExtensionPack\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"
>   cannot be imported again. It was
>   already imported at
>   "D:...\Tasker.proj (5,3)". This is
>   most likely a build authoring error.
>   This subsequent import will be
>   ignored.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this warning message? Please help!

Comment: Um... Don't import more than once?

Comment: I filed https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/726728/msbuild-warning-msb4011-for-multiple-imports-is-harmful-for-property-sheets#tabs for this problem.

Comment: Also, check your csproj for duplicate imports.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The work-around of this question would be: Calling the import with condition to check the existence of a unique property defined in the considering project file. Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to add a comment with a code snippet from where this question was asked elsewhere: `<Import Project="Tasks.targets" Condition=" '$(TasksTargetsImported)' == '' "/>` where `Tasks.targets` has in it `<PropertyGroup><TasksTargetsImported>true</TasksTargetsImported></PropertyGroup>`

Comment: And if I really want to include smth twice? With different parameters maybe. C++ folks would do this a lot.

Comment: Conditions also are not re-eavaluated when running build in VS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92x05xfs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That warning has happened to me when I have built my application from VS IDE and by MSBuild tool in parallel. I guess the same might happen when  you work with more than one VS window on the same project

Answer (score -1):

Delete the automatically generated file yourproject.nuget.props and the warning will go away.