# Want to include a system .props file, but it causes a warning that it is already included

Tags: c++, msbuild

My .props file contains an import of "$(VCTargetsPath12)Microsoft.Cpp.mfcDynamic.props", but in one project which I include the .props file, it already uses that file and I get the following warning:

```
D:\Projects\UnitTest\ab32\ab32.props(4,5): warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.mfcDynamic.props" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.Cpp.Common.props (445,5)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [D:\Projects\UnitTest\ab32\ab32.vcxproj]
```

I saw [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2544926/how-to-get-import-custom-tasks-more-than-once-without-warning-message), but it doesn't work in this case as it is a system one that I will not modify.  Though I did try:

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath12)Microsoft.Cpp.mfcDynamic.props" Condition=" '$(_PropertySheetDisplayName)' != 'Dynamic Link to MFC' " />
```

But it didn't work.  Suggestions?

Comment: If that property sheet modifies other things (itemgroups, ...) you could check on those instead?

Comment: @stijn, how do I check those?

Comment: mfcDynamic adds _AFXDLL to the preprocessor definitions so something like `@(ClCompile->'%(PreprocessorDefinitions)'->Contains('_AFXDLL'))` can be used to check that, but afaik only inside a target so I don't know directly how to do that on the project level, sorry..

Comment: @stijn, where did you find that information?

Comment: You mean that it defines _AFXDLL? I just opened the property sheet in a text editor.

Comment: @stijn No. The @ syntax and what can be put within the parenthesis.

Comment: The first `->` is a 'transform': https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171476.aspx so this creates a new item list, the second `->` invokes an 'item function' on each element of the list, the 'Contains' function of .Net String in this case: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee886422.aspx

Comment: @stijn cool. I'll look it up.

Comment: @stijn, this sounded like a good idea, but it didn't work.  I get the following error: `A reference to an item list at position 1 is not allowed in this condition "@(ClCompile->'%(PreprocessorDefinitions)'->Contains('_AFXDLL'))".` and I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Not sure exactly, but this can detect _AFXDLL properly: https://gist.github.com/stinos/05d93f9b89e1cc7d5930 As I said though, it can only do that at the Target level so I doubt it's useful.